# Backbone.JS view renders, but not displayed on page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework, singlepage

I'm working on converting a single-page app to backbone.JS. The View below uses the body tag as it's tagName - ie, I want the view to occupy the entire content of the page. I don't want to use container divs or other hacks.

```
var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({  
    tagName : "body",
            ... 


    // Show the HTML for the view 
    render : function() {  
        console.log('Displaying thing')
        $(this.el).append('<h1>test</h1>');
        console.log('finished')
        console.log($(this.el))
        return this; // For chaining
```

When rendering, I see

```
finished
[
<body>​
    <h1>​test​</h1>​
</body>​
]
```

But after I inspect the DOM, the body no longer has the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tagName` indicates what tag Backbone should use to create its el if no el is provided by the constructor. The created element is not automatically inserted into the DOM.

The simplest way is probably to create your view with its el set to `body` :

```
new ThingView({el:'body'})
```

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr - that works. I've actually just specified 'el' directly in the constructor, as ThingViews will always be attached to the same element, and it works too.

Comment: One further question: if I specify el directly, does it find the element in the existing document, but if I use tagName (etc) it creates a new element in memory that will beed to be attached to the DOM?

Comment: @nailer Exactly. Backbone expects an element, attached to the DOM or not. Building it in memory before attaching it avoids unnecessary page reflows, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What nikoshr explained is correct. Adding to it, Using tagName is correct. but Ideally you should use el element, which is defined in Backbone.js library as an element (el) of View.

Below is the ideal code you should use while doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  
             var ThingView  = Backbone.View.extend({
                    el:$("body"),                   
                    initialize: function(){
                            _.bindAll(this,"render");
                            this.render();  
                    },
                    render:function(){
                        this.el.append('<h1>test</h1>');    
                        console.log('finished');
                        console.log($(this.el).html());                     
                    }
                });    
                var ThingView = new ThingView();
            });
</script>
```